# Accessing variables in transformer

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm running Mule CE and in one of my flows I'm accessing a static XML fil containging complex objects.
I read this one using a bean and save it in a variable.

```
<set-variable variableName="Settings" value="#[app.registry['LoadSetting']]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

So far so good.
In my Transformer I then need to read these values, find the object with the right key and fill in some values in my payload. 
So, how can i access this variable in my Transformer class, like

```
message.getInvocationProperty("test");
```

As far as I understand, the "message" itself isn't avilable.. or is it?

I did find the advicein the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457176/mule-studio-pass-set-variable-to-java-transformer) but I didn't really understand that answer (it's Friday after all..)

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share your Transformation class?

Basically, you can access the "message", if your Transformation class extends `org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer`. You can find some simple examples from [Mule User Guide](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/java-transformer-reference) or [Slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/SulthonyHartanto/mule-java-transformer).

As another alternative, your can use the `@Expr` [annotation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-connector-devkit/v/3.7/annotation-reference). For example, pass this expression `@Expr("flowVars['Settings']") String myFlowVarSettings` as the argument to your Transformation class. Then use it to finalize the payload.

Comment: Thanks for answering, yes I'm overriding "doTransform". I'll see if I can get my hands on that message. Never read about the @Expr alternative, looks nice

Comment: Silly me, i did extend the AbstractTransformer, not the AbstractMessageTransformer. Big difference. However, it didn't enjoy any "@Expr" annotations though, but I can get it with the .getInvocationProperty() - big thanks!